# Let $H \leq G$. If $G = H H^x$ then $G=H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H \leq G$. If $G = H H^x$ then $G=H$.

According to the source, it should solve with elementary knowledge of group theory, but my tries have no result! Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does $H^x$ denote?

Comment: $H^x = x^{-1} H x$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $G=HH^x$, there exist $u,v \in H$ such that $x = uv^x$. But $uv^x = ux^{-1}vx$ so that $ux^{-1}v = 1$ and $x \in H$.

Finally, $G=HH^x=HH=H$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $G=HH^x$ and $x \in G$ , $x=hx^{-1}kx$ for certain $h, k \in H$. It follows that $x=kh$. Therefore $x \in H$, so $H^x=H$. As a result $G=H$.